# Run Incron Daemon as Normal User Rather Than as Root

Tags: permissions, systemd, incron

I need to run [incron](https://github.com/ar-/incron)d to respond to a FUSE directory that is mounted without the `allow_root` option.  That means I have to run it as my own user.  When I install incron as default under systemd and then create an incrontab as myself, I find:

```
$ ps -eo euser,ruser,suser,fuser,f,comm,label | grep incron
root     root     root     root     5 incrond         unconfined
```

How can I change this daemon to run under my own username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this question is moot.  Incron (and inotify) need to run as root, but even if it were not the case, FUSE also does not provide for monitoring of filesystem events.  It is apparently [possible](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/Fsnotify-and-FUSE), but the developers [have labeled it a "won't fix."](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs/issues/215).